# live graph ploting in using c programming

Tags: c, linux, graph

hi every one is there a way by which i can draw live graph using c programming. like i have some values stored in a csv file i will add values of the column and plot them in a graph.a real-time plotter that can automatically update graphs of my data while it is still being computed by my application.and how can i append the graph in a gui.and use that graph plotter in my c program.

thanks any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This really depends upon the gui - which one are you using? for example: windows, mac, linux (x/gnome/K), webpage, framebuffer.

Comment: ok, that still leaves the field wide open.  What GUI does your application have now (or have you not decided yet?).  If you know it has a GUI but are not sure, then what development kit are you using to develop your application, or what desktop are you using.  If you haven't decided yet, then take a look at opengl, sdl, gnome and kde.

Comment: are you more interested in having the graph, or doing the programming?  There are probably existing applications or applets that will draw such a graph.

Comment: sir i am interested in programming. for gui i have selected gtk actually i have a c code which will compute some values i want to show these value in graph using c programming and also want some gui having buttons or labels a drop down memu from which i will select the file name and press button then graph of that file will apper

Comment: Fine, so please indicate the challenge you currently face?  for instance "I don't know where to start, please point me at the gtk documentation", or "I tried this <example> but it didn't work, can you look at my code and help?"

Comment: sir same as your question " i do not know where to start" i was reading a tutorial and found gnuplot.so i think that i should go for gnuplot and gtk.but i am stuck having no knowledge of both gnuplot and gtk :(  as i have mentioned above i want an interface in which i haves file names i select a file and press "PLOT GRAPH" button and graph must appear (live graph as values are continously updating) sir kindly guide me how to start. i am reading tutorials and try to under stand gtk and gnuplot

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look.  I suggest you pick gtk, and forget gnuplot for now (I really dislike gnuplot).  See my answer, below.

Comment: ok sir kindly guide me that if not gnuplot then how should i plot graph.and how to start thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) can read data from a pipe so you can update the plot from your code - and you don'y have to handle any gui or windowing code yourself

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by doing some GTK programming tutorials.

Here's a simple tutorial/example of line drawing to get you started.

http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/2.99/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html.en

Also so some sketches (with a pen, on paper) of what you think it should look like.

---

Since you said you are interested in this as a programming exercise, I also offer the following hints:

You will need to work out answers to the following questions:

```
* How shall I save the graph data (csv I guess)
* How can I read the graph data into my program?
* How shall I detect when the graph data has changed
* How shall I plot the graph
* How shall I plot the graph metadata, such as axes, titles, scales etc.
* How shall I deal with the data as more and more arrives?
```

Good luck, and come back to stackoverflow when you get stuck

Comment: thank u so much sir.please just answer my one question only that can i also draw graph using gtk

Comment: If you can draw a line, you can draw a graph.  You need to consider scaling first.